# CSS angle border as button with text over

Tags: html, css, border, angle

http://jsfiddle.net/NEgv6/

I want to do this with css and no images because the text will not be the same so the angle border (background) wil expand

I saw this method on Google Play (https://play.google.com/store) page and I inspect the element but I can't make it work in my situation

Solved http://jsfiddle.net/NEgv6/5/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "angle border"? I don't see anything on the Google Play link that looks like what you posted.

Comment: the black tabs (TOP CHARTS, CATEGORIES, STAFF PICKS) just look at the page code you will see it's angle border mine is jut reverse

Comment: Try giving your anchor a position: relative, then you can set top:-31px; or whatever you want.

Comment: thanks it work... I can't belive I didn't try top:..; instead I've tried all margin-top padding-top combinations

Comment: Yeah I'm not really sure why those didn't do anything. You have a lot of strangely-positioned elements in there though, you might want to consider revamping and cleaning that up a bit. 

Edit: Ah, the anchor is an inline element, thus ignoring margin and padding.

Comment: @Selei: Weird... I must be seeing a different layout from you. I don't see those tabs anywhere. It might be a regional thing, or due to some difference in Google accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good base: http://jsfiddle.net/NEgv6/2/